# DotNetNuke MySQL

Tags: mysql, dotnetnuke

Windows Server 2003.  I have an existing DotNetNuke website. SQL Server is currently running and is being used by DotNetNuke.  I want to use MySQL for other purposes. Would installing MySQL on the same server interfere with DotNetNuke?

It seems that shortly after installing DotNetNuke our website stopped populating pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, installing MySQL should have no impact on the dotnetnuke installation.